# Calculate sample size (DeMoivre-Laplace)

Tags: probability, self-study, sample-size

I have difficulties with calculating sample size. 
In the task the question is what sample size is needed to prove whether CTR changes or not.

There is a banner with CTR = 1,5 %
Also there is a new one (4% of all shows). I need to calculate how many times the page should be shown to understand whether CTR changes or not (significance level = 5%)

As far as I remember there is DeMoivre-Laplace theorem, but i'm not sure if y formula is correct

P(|(m/n) - p| < e) = 0.95
Also, I'm not sure is e = 1-0.95 (error)

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: 95% is probably a confidence level $1-\alpha$, not significance, the latter is often $\alpha=0.05$

Comment: @Aksakal as far as I understood from the question it was significance level, - alpha

Comment: Yevgenyia - the significance level is the chosen type I error rate (the probability of incorrectly rejecting the null hypothesis when it's true). Choosing it to be 0.95 means you're almost always saying H0 is false when it's true. This would not normally make any sense. If that's what the question said the person who wrote it made a serious mistake.

Comment: @Glen_b While trying to calculate it I found some similar tasks. The idea is to calculate how many observations we need to prove (exactly to 95%) that CTR (or other probability like 'eagle'/'tail' probability) has changed or not

Comment: I have no clear idea what you actually mean by "prove (exactly to 95%)" there. Correct definitions of terms like [significance level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance#Role_in_statistical_hypothesis_testing)  are easy to find. [Just as people explaining physics ideas don't get to make up their own incompatible definitions for "force" or "momentum" -- at least not if they hope to be taken seriously.] Flouting the conventional meaning of "significance level" will be widely - and I think rightly - treated as an error.

Comment: @Glen_b that's correct and I meant significance level in my question. Still it doesn't help me to solve the problem )

Comment: It still says "significance = 95%"; and I'm still sure that you don't want to choose a type I error rate that high. You either want to change the word (to something that goes with 95%) or change the number (to something that goes with "significance")